# System.Net.SocketException in Socket.Connect - (0x80004005) Unknown host

Tags: c#, socketexception

I am facing some problems with connect method while attempting to connect to a remote host. The main task deals with an industrial device which accepts TCP connections. The PC has two network cards with different networks families. It seems that the connect method is not able to reach the correct IP address. In fact, if I try to unplug the other network, everything works properly. Variables IPAddress and Port are set from the software. The error is:

> System.NetSockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Unknown host at
> System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostEntry()

Below the code:

```
public void Connect() 
{
    int port;
    try
    {
        int.TryParse(Port, out port);
        socketMarking = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);    

        SocketAsyncEventArgs telnetSocketAsyncEventArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        telnetSocketAsyncEventArgs.RemoteEndPoint       = new IPEndPoint(Dns.GetHostEntry(IPAddress.Trim()).AddressList[0].MapToIPv4(), port);
        telnetSocketAsyncEventArgs.Completed            += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(telnetSocketAsyncEventArgs_Completed);
        
        socketMarking.ReceiveTimeout    = 3000;
        
        socketMarking.Connect(IPAddress, port);
        streamWrite                     = new NetworkStream(socketMarking);
        
        Connected                         = true;                   
    }
   catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        main.AddMessage("Socket error on IP " + IPAddress + ":" + Port + "-->"+ex.ToString());                       
    }
}
```

Another discussion point is that debugging on two different PC everything works, but only on that one I have this kind of problem. All firewalls and possible protections are disabled.

Comment: Look at `Dns.GetHostEntry(IPAddress.Trim()).AddressList[0].MapToIPv4()` line. If possible - in debug mode. Probably `IPAddress` value isn't valid hostname or IP.